# How to run screen as non-root user in CentOS 5

Tags: centos, gnu-screen, non-root-user

I've followed this guide http://centoshelp.org/resources/scripts-tools/a-basic-understanding-of-screen-on-centos/

Now, seems like I am having trouble running screen with non-root user, because everytime I run screen it only shows
`[remote detached]`

what does it mean?

Comment: How exactly do you run it? Just `screen`, or do you use any parameters? Are you sure that it isn't running? Have you tried a screen key combination like `^a ?`?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I type `screen` without params, I got `[remote detached]`, key combinations only work on root.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`screen` to start a new screen session

`screen -rd` to attach to one that is running

**ctrl-a**, **d** to disconnect from an attached session

Comment: yes sir. It works great with root user. But my non-root user is showing different. screen would output [remote detached], putty changed its windows title to screen, but actually I am not in screen.

If I type screen -rd, it would output `There is no screen to be detached`

Comment: Ah, screen sessions are per user, unless one attaches specifically to a screen session. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes sir. I want the non-root user to have its own screen session.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same 'remote detached' message if I attempt to attach a screen session that is already the active session. You could try exiting the current shell, but before you do, please try running

`screen -list`

This will list all screen sessions for the logged in user as well as their status. If you see one that is attached, it may very well be your current shell.

Comment: Sir: `No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-tgr` so nothing is attached.